# how to upload multiple image in my backend component joomla form

Tags: joomla, components

I am developing a component in J! 2.5 and want to add a browse button on the backend so the user can pick a file they have previously uploaded but when I use a media type in the form.xml I can upload only one picture.

I use the code below in a xml file but I can upload only one picture?
How would I go about this?

```xml
<field name="image" 
   type="media" 
   label=""
   description="" 
   class="inputbox"
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML you have to define new element

```
<field name="image" type="myelement" label="" description="" class="inputbox" />
```

Now create file `models/fields/myelement.php` If you use XML file to load form from `models/forms/myform.xml` it will be found automatically. If not add attridute to `<fieldset>` parent element

```
addfieldpath="/components/com_custom/models/fields/"
```

Now in that file create class.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die();

jimport('joomla.html.html');
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldMyelement extends JFormField
{
    public $type = 'Myelement';

    public function getInput()
    {

    }
}
```

Now return whatever you want. You can incorporate any 3d party uploader. For examples what to return in `getInput()` start typing JFormField and you will see in dropdown available classes.

[image: list of classes]